# Get the row or column of the cell with a given value within a given 2D range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm in need of a way to return either the row or column of the cell that has a specified value in a given 2D range of cells.

In other words, I would be interested in a pair of functions ROW(value, range) and COLUMN(value, range).

This seems like a simple enough request, and yet all the lookup-type functions seem to be array-based.

Comment: Do you want the values relative to the start of the worksheet *(A1)* or relative to the start of the 2D range *??*

Comment: I'd like them relative to A1

Comment: I have shown **both** ways !

Comment: Two questions: 1. is this a step into returning a value using ADDRESS/OFFSET and /or INDIRECT?  If so there are faster methods that skip this step.  2. Are there duplicates in the look up values?

Comment: No duplicate values. The end goal is to return the value of the cell that is the intersection of a returned row value and column value. (i.e. my search values are table labels)

Comment: Then there is a much easier way using INDEX/MATCH/MATCH in a non array form.  Your question doe not ask that.

Comment: See my edit below.

Comment: Can that formula account for uncertainty regarding where in the page the table labels appear? That's a requirement of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a non CSE method.

It takes into consideration that there may be duplicates in the data.  The first search is for the lowest row:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$F$5)-ROW($B$2)+1)/($B$2:$F$5=$A$7),1),"No Match")
```

The next finds the lowest column in that row.  So if there are duplicates it returns the lowest column in the lowest row that the value is found.

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(INDEX($B$2:$F$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$F$5)-ROW($B$2)+1)/($B$2:$F$5=$A$7),1),0))-COLUMN($B$2)+1)/(INDEX($B$2:$F$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$F$5)-ROW($B$2)+1)/($B$2:$F$5=$A$7),1),0)=$A$7),1),"No Match")
```

It has an error handler, if the value is not found it will return "No Match"

[image]

---

As per your comment above I think you would rather have this formula.

```
=INDEX(A:F,MATCH(A7,A:A,0),MATCH(A8,1:1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. I appreciate the attention to edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to locate that ***100***.
In **A7** enter 100.  In **B8** enter the array formula:

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$F$5=A7,COLUMN($B$2:$F$5)-COLUMN($B$2)+1))
```

In **B9** enter the array formula:

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$F$5=A7,ROW($B$2:$F$5)-ROW($B$2)+1))
```

These give the row and column **relative to the table start(B2)**:

[image]

To get the row / column with regard to the start of the worksheet, just use **$A$1** in place of **$B$2** in the formulas.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: If the OP is hoping for the coordinates to use later, then this runs the risk of false positives if there are doubles.  For Example, put 100 in E3.  The coordinates will return 2,2 the first column and first row. which may be what the OP is looking for, but if the OP want coordinates it will have returned the row and column of the 97 in C3.  Just an observation.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Good Points !  I did not consider *nomatch* or *dupmatch* in my answer.....